# How to store Data.ByteString in database

Tags: haskell, persist, bytestring

I have a `User` model which has a salt and I'd like to save it in my data base.

My model looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Database.Persist.TH (mkMigrate, mkPersist, persistLowerCase, share, sqlSettings)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

share -- line 50
  [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
  [persistLowerCase|
User json
  username String
  passwordHash String Maybe
  salt ByteString 
  publicRsaKey String 
  privateRsaKey String
  UserName username
|]
```

but ghc then gives me an error

```
/workspace/src/Admin.hs:50:1: error:
    • No instance for (FromJSON ByteString) arising from a use of ‘.:’
    • In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
        ‘(obj_a8aN .: T.pack "salt")’
      In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
        ‘(((pure User <*> (obj_a8aN .: T.pack "username"))
             <*> (obj_a8aN .:? T.pack "passwordHash"))
            <*> (obj_a8aN .: T.pack "salt"))’
      In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
        ‘((((pure User <*> (obj_a8aN .: T.pack "username"))
              <*> (obj_a8aN .:? T.pack "passwordHash"))
             <*> (obj_a8aN .: T.pack "salt"))
            <*> (obj_a8aN .: T.pack "publicRsaKey"))’
   |
50 | share
   | ^^^^^...

/workspace/src/Admin.hs:50:1: error:
    • No instance for (ToJSON ByteString) arising from a use of ‘.=’
    • In the expression: (T.pack "salt" .= salt_a8aQ)
      In the first argument of ‘object’, namely
        ‘[(T.pack "username" .= username_a8aO),
          (T.pack "passwordHash" .= passwordHash_a8aP),
          (T.pack "salt" .= salt_a8aQ),
          (T.pack "publicRsaKey" .= publicRsaKey_a8aR), ....]’
      In the expression:
        object
          [(T.pack "username" .= username_a8aO),
           (T.pack "passwordHash" .= passwordHash_a8aP),
           (T.pack "salt" .= salt_a8aQ),
           (T.pack "publicRsaKey" .= publicRsaKey_a8aR), ....]
   |
50 | share
   | ^^^^^...
```

My question now is how can I store a `Data.ByteString` in my database?

Comment: How do you want the ByteString returned from `pack "as\x89f"` to be encoded in JSON?

Comment: There's no default json encoding for bytes. I suggest you use text instead and encode the bytes in base64.  A newtype would make sense.